# Подключение Free-kassa к Telegram боту

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем добрый день. Захотелось сделать телеграм бота на Python. Если пользователь нажимает на кнопку (бот присылает сообщение и кнопку), то он переходит на оплату товара **(в моем случаи товар - это подписка, причем подписка имеет определённый срок действия для разных кнопок).** оплату хочу реализовать с помощью Free-kassa. Не понимаю, **как привязать Free-kassa к телеграм боту**. Подскажите пожалуйста что для этого нужно? В интернете не нашел статьи на тему: Привязка free-kassa к телеграм боту. И какие вообще знания для этого нужны? Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У них в FAQ есть небольшая информация об оформлении приёма для телеграм-ботов:

https://www.free-kassa.ru/faq.php

Теперь к баранам-кнопкам. В кнопки вы закладываете ссылки. Ссылки ведут на оплату какого-либо товара или какой-либо услуги. Надо как-то получить такие ссылки. Как? Это делается через ЛК (или как называется его аналог у них?). Там же можно получить всю остальную информацию. Тем более у них не самый ужасный саппорт.

Про API почитать можно туточки:

https://www.free-kassa.ru/docs/api.php

Частично расписано, частично опущено. Согласен, документация не очень. Но стоит начать с неё.

Comment: подскажите, а нужна ли для этого бд?

Comment: Скорее всего, не нужна. Но стоит уточнить у поддержки

Comment: понял, а чтбы сделать админ панель - что нужно? для этого бд нужна?

Comment: Какую админ панель? Всё можно сделать без базы данных, на обычных текстовых файлах. Только насколько это будет больно в реализации

Comment: админ панель, где будет отображаться id покупателя, и название купленного продукта. тут мне JSON в помощь?

Comment: Можно же это реализовать просто отправкой сообщений ботом в ТГ

Comment: эти данные должен видеть только админ, человек покупает товар, и его id отображается в так называемой "админ панели". Вот как реализовать эту админ панель - не понятно

Comment: порчел Получение ответа в формате JSON на free-kassa API, но как парсить эти данные? и откуда и куда...